# SQLi Filter Bypass with banned table/column names

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, mysql, sqlmap, filter

I've studying and practicing different approach to SQLi filter bypass and I faced a challenge. What if the WAF filters look for specific strings rather than SQL keywords?

Example:

```
Filter: /UNION/
SQLi: UnIoN

Filter: /UNION/i
SQLi: un/**/ion

Filter: /UNION/i and no comments
SQLi: un%0bion
```

So far, so good. There are lots of valid articles that explain how to surpass filters based on keywords. What if the banned string is a table/column name, or a part of it?

```
Filter: /user/i
SQLi: SELECT username FROM users; # deny. username matches /user/i

Filter: /or/i
SQLi: SELECT password from users; # deny. passwORd matches /or/i
```

I tried with double encoding, unicode encoding, splitting the column names ``` use``rname ``` (which doesn't work) but no approach seems to be working. Mostly because my understanding is that it's the web application that decodes the input before it's passed to the Mysql database and, therefore, the syntax must be correct before the query is processed by the database, but still encoded at the time the WAF Filters are applied.

Is there a generic approach to deal with this scenarios?

Comment: Is this a general question or have you run into a specific system that does this? I ask because I suspect this is a theoretical problem, not a practical one.  Most WAFs are generic and not tuned to the specific application, and doing this could quickly become a source of false positives. As a result I suspect it is rarely a practical concern

Answer (score 0):

You can do things to *reference* the table or column name from the schema instead of supplying the actual name.